# Get position of date on the x axis

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I have set the following `xlim` on my x axis:

```
axA.set_xlim(datetime.date(2016, 12, 1), datetime.date(2018, 1, 30))
```

and now I would like to get the position of the 12th of October (2017-10-12) on my X axis, so that I can then put an annotation there.

I tried to figure that out the using `date2num` and `datestr2num`:

```
release_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 12)

print(mdates.date2num(release_date))
print(mdates.datestr2num('2017-10-12'))

print(axA.get_xlim())
```

The above code output:

```
-736614.0
736614.0

(17136.0, 17561.0)
```

First it seems like `date2num` and `datestr2num` don't give an identical result, but more problematically, those results are not within the range of `xlim`.

How can I find the X position of a date (to place an annotation), given the `xlim` I set above?

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime


def get_dataframe():
    values = [12, 16, 20]
    dates = [
        datetime(2017, 12, 24),
        datetime(2017, 12, 23),
        datetime(2017, 12, 22)
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates, 'value': values})
    df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index()

    return df


def plot(dataA):
    fig, axA = plt.subplots()
    dataA.plot(ax=axA)

    axA.set_xlim(datetime(2016, 12, 1), datetime(2018, 1, 30))

    release = datetime(2017, 10, 12)
    print(mdates.date2num(release))
    print(mdates.datestr2num('2017-10-12'))
    print(axA.get_xlim())


df = get_dataframe()
plot(df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Running the code gives `736614.0 736614.0 (736299.0, 736724.0)` for me. What matplotlib version are you using? Again, a [mcve] would help a lot finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a date object directly if you have a date xaxis:

```
ax.annotate('hello', xy=(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 12), 1),  
            xytext=(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 12), 5), 
            arrowprops={'facecolor': 'r'})
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves the issue though. If the axis limits are off as shown in the question, the annotation would probably not be shown correctly either.